# Azure API Management import OpenApi - Parsing error(s): The reference string has invalid format

Tags: openapi, azure-api-management

I'm trying to import a valid OpenApi yaml doc into Azure API Management. The doc is valid according to [editor.swagger.io](https://editor.swagger.io/).

This doc is autogenerated using [speccy](https://github.com/wework/speccy) to combine multiple yamls into one.

Here's a truncated version of my OpenApi doc:

```
openapi: 3.0.2
info:
  title: My API
  version: "1.0"
servers:
  - url: https://api.server.test/v1
paths:
  "/account/{accountId}/billSummary":
    get:
      summary: get bill summary for account
      description: |
        Bill summary for account including bill statement breakdown
      tags:
        - Account bill summary
      parameters:
        - name: accountId
          in: path
          required: true
          description: Account id
          schema:
            type: string
            maximum: 12
            pattern: "[0-9]+"
      responses:
        "400":
          description: The accountId is invalid
          content:
            application/problem+json:
              schema:
                title: ProblemDetails
                type: object
                properties:
                  type:
                    type: string
                    format: uri
                    example: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.4
                  title:
                    type: string
                    example: Not Found
                  status:
                    type: integer
                    example: 404
                  traceId:
                    type: string
                    format: uuid
                    example: 00-e1f13d1f98e0b9273e7ccbdf50376e7d-684a978b72c01f49-00
                  errors:
                    type: object
                    nullable: true
        "404":
          description: The account is not found
          content:
            application/problem+json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/paths/~1account~1%7BaccountId%7D~1billSummary/get/responses/400/conten\
                  t/application~1problem%2Bjson/schema"
        "500":
          description: An unexpected error occurred
          content:
            application/problem+json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/paths/~1account~1%7BaccountId%7D~1billSummary/get/responses/400/conten\
                  t/application~1problem%2Bjson/schema"
```

My issue is that the 404 response schema is a reference to the the ProblemDetails object which is defined in the 400 response.

API Management throws an error when I try to import it:

```
Parsing error(s): The reference string '/paths/~1account~1%7BaccountId%7D~1billSummary/get/responses/400/content/application~1problem%2Bjson/schema' has invalid format. [#/paths//account/{accountId}/billSummary/get/responses/404/content/schema] The reference string '/paths/~1account~1%7BaccountId%7D~1billSummary/get/responses/400/content/application~1problem%2Bjson/schema' has invalid format. [#/paths//account/{accountId}/billSummary/get/responses/500/content/schema]
```

I tried other tools to merge my yamls instead of speccy, e.g. `swagger-merge` and it's output is the same.

I can manually workaround it by changing the yaml - adding the ProblemDetails as a component, but that's not desirable as I'm trying to automate this as part of a release pipeline.

A manual workaround looks like:

```
openapi: 3.0.2
info:
  title: Self Service API
  version: "1.0"
servers:
  - url: https://api.server.test/v1
paths:
  "/account/{accountId}/billSummary":
    get:
      summary: get bill summary for account
      description: |
        Bill summary for account including bill statement breakdown
      tags:
        - Account bill summary
      parameters:
        - name: accountId
          in: path
          required: true
          description: Account id
          schema:
            type: string
            maximum: 12
            pattern: "[0-9]+"
      responses:
        "400":
          description: The accountId is invalid
          content:
            application/problem+json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/ProblemDetails"
        "404":
          description: The account is not found
          content:
            application/problem+json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/ProblemDetails"
        "500":
          description: An unexpected error occurred
          content:
            application/problem+json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/ProblemDetails"
components:
  schemas:
    ProblemDetails:
      type: object
      properties: 
        type:
          type: string
          format: uri
          example: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.4
        title:
          type: string
          example: Not Found
        status:
          type: integer
          example: 404
        traceId:
          type: string
          format: uuid
          example: 00-e1f13d1f98e0b9273e7ccbdf50376e7d-684a978b72c01f49-00
        errors:
          type: object
          nullable: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I raised a support request with Microsoft for this, and apparently this is considered recursion, which is not supported.

> Recursion: API Management doesn't support definitions defined recursively.
> For example, schemas referring to themselves.

Source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-api-import-restrictions